# laravel passport create token but not working on centos7

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

Laravel Passport works locally on Windows properly.But by transferring to the Linux server, it doesn't work properly by creating tokens and all configurations.And it always returns error 401

Comment: Have you installed passport in the Linux server properly and generate the secrets?

Comment: yes, token is created, but Auth::user() output is empty

Comment: In the local environment, the same code works properly

Comment: production environment is centos 7

Comment: 401 means an unauthorized client. If the code worked in your local env then nothing's wrong in code. You have to check the configuration for passport in centos 7, and also check if the env variables are set properly.

Answer (score 1):

the httpd.conf file I added the line (Linux/CentOS 7.6):

SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

Comment: in apache web server ?